# GAE Blobstore: ImagesService.getServingUrl() gives me smaller images

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm uploading some images to GAE's Blobstore. Upload goes succesfully and when i see the images in GAE console i can see that they're stored in the expected size and resolution.

According to [this site](http://ikaisays.com/2010/09/08/gwt-blobstore-the-new-high-performance-image-serving-api-and-cute-dogs-on-office-chairs/), to get a URL to the uploaded image i can use this:

```
BlobKey blobKey = (BlobKey) blobs.get("image");
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
String imageUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(blobKey);
```

The resulting URL points to a smaller version of the uploaded images (in size and quality). How can i get a URL to the full size image stored in Blobstore?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can append =s0 parameter after the url to get full sized image.